# when the menu is mouseover, it disappears when I click on an input and I take it in focus

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, fadeout, mouseleave

I have a div that when she flew brings up a menu where people can log.
The problem is that when a person click on the input and wants to get an address that is already registered, the menu disappears

the jquery :

```
  $("#div-account").hide();
  $("#ul").hover(function() {
      $("#div-account").fadeIn(200);
      $("#arrow").attr('src', 'arrow.png');
    },
    function() {
      $("#div-account").fadeOut(200);
      $("#arrow").attr('src', 'arrow2.png');
  });
```

image to illustrate :
[image: when i select natural auto complete][image: when i focus element before select auto choice]

Comment: you need to post your related HTML codes too..

Comment: Try to use mouseenter/mouseleave instead of hover

Comment: you have example on : thiais.yakarouler.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this as my comment suggest:

```
$("#div-account").hide();
$("#ul").on('mouseenter',function() {
      $("#div-account").fadeIn(200);
      $("#arrow").attr('src', 'arrow.png');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
      $("#div-account").fadeOut(200);
      $("#arrow").attr('src', 'arrow2.png');
});
```

Comment: i've this error when i trying => TypeError: $(...).on is not a function (i use 1.4.2 version of jquery i cant change..)

Comment: Use bind() instead of on()